Install sifreader 0.2.4
I'm trying to install the python package found in this website: https://pypi.org/project/sifreader/.
But when I use pip install, I get this message:

[7 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tqi13wln\sifreader_34236a7cd03c4b18a89f9576d7ca2db7\setup.py", line 13, in 
long_description = open('readme.md').read(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'readme.md'
[end of output]

And indee, looking at the tar file, there's no readme.md file, but at the same time this line is commented on the setup.py file, so what coulld I do in this situation?
I tried  deleting the line which is causing trouble, but then Anaconda tells me that it can't compile it.

Looking at sifreader's repository, it appears that the package is no longer maintained, I would recommend using another package like sif_parser instead.

You can install from sources.
To do that, you can either clone the repository and install from local files:
git clone git@github.com:lightingghost/sifreader.git && cd sifreader
pip install .

Or, you can use a direct reference to the git repository on github:
pip install sifreader@git+https://github.com/lightingghost/sifreader.git@master

You should have something like this as a result:
Collecting sifreader@ git+https://github.com/lightingghost/sifreader.git@master
  Cloning https://github.com/lightingghost/sifreader.git (to revision master) to /tmp/pip-install-4__5b1j6/sifreader_a0174e1516b54556a9f98075a2850834
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/lightingghost/sifreader.git /tmp/pip-install-4__5b1j6/sifreader_a0174e1516b54556a9f98075a2850834
  Resolved https://github.com/lightingghost/sifreader.git to commit fafbaab71885c9a8f7d44da56fafc65233f10bae
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from sifreader@ git+https://github.com/lightingghost/sifreader.git@master) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: sifreader
  Building wheel for sifreader (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for sifreader: filename=sifreader-0.2.4-py3-none-any.whl size=6665 sha256=8319e3e4c41b9f4889047b3baad85e73eb6c62a18df1d131ef798057f724daa1
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-yygme2ps/wheels/a9/25/f6/fa74580386d5659a85c34814ec566faea4a038ee19af0f4ad0
Successfully built sifreader
Installing collected packages: sifreader
Successfully installed sifreader-0.2.4

Even if this works, I advise you to look for maintained alternatives as mentionned by @franco227
